# How to ensure messages reach kafka broker?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have have a message producer on my local machine and a broker on remote host (aws).

After sending a message from the producer,
I wait and call the console consumer on the remote host and
see excessive logs.
Without the value from producer.

The producer flushes the data after calling the send method.
Everything is configured correctly.

How can I check to see that the broker received the message from the producer and to see if the producer received the answer?

Comment: Do you basically mean your producer isn't working? What do you mean by "see exessive logs"? Have you configured the listeners on your brokers correctly?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt I meant there a lot of meaningless logs(without actual value) in console after executing console consumer.

What is interesting is after moving brokers to local machine and edit URL everything works correctly . I wonder how can I tackle communication with brokers on AWS. Again, I opend all inbound and outbound ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Send` method asynchronously sends the message to the topic and
returns a `Future` of `RecordMetadata`.

`java.util.concurrent.Future<RecordMetadata> send(ProducerRecord<K,V> record)`

> Asynchronously sends a record to a topic

After the `flush` call,
check to see that the Future has completed by calling the `isDone` method.
(for example, `Future.isDone() == true`)

> Invoking this method makes all buffered records immediately available to send (even if linger.ms is greater than 0) and blocks on the completion of the requests associated with these records. The post-condition of flush() is that any previously sent record will have completed (e.g. Future.isDone() == true). A request is considered completed when it is successfully acknowledged according to the acks configuration you have specified or else it results in an error.

The `RecordMetadata` contains the `offset` and the `partition`

**public int partition()**

> The partition the record was sent to

**public long offset()**

> the offset of the record, or -1 if {hasOffset()} returns false.

Or you can also use [Callback](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html#send-org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord-org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Callback-) function to ensure messages was sent to topic or not

> Fully non-blocking usage can make use of the Callback parameter to provide a callback that will be invoked when the request is complete.

here is clear example in docs

```
 ProducerRecord<byte[],byte[]> record = new ProducerRecord<byte[],byte[]>("the-topic", key, value);
 producer.send(myRecord,
           new Callback() {
               public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception e) {
                   if(e != null) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                   } else {
                      System.out.println("The offset of the record we just sent is: " + metadata.offset());
                   }
               }
           });
```

Comment: I sent the batch to remote brokers. As long as it reached the broker new partition was created(it was new partition). But I cannot see messages i sent to this partition.

Comment: are those altered partitions @voipp

Comment: I just moved broker on local machine and everything works fine

Comment: @Deadpool, if hasOffset()returns true, can i say that the topic has received the message?

Comment: Yes you can @jumping_monkey

Comment: @Deadpool, thanks. Would it be wrong if i just call .get() in the try block. If the topic receive the message, the flow will never go to the catch block, and if the topic did not receive the message, the flow will go to the catch block? I would like to know what is the best practice, my goal is to always check that the message has reached the topic.

Comment: @Deadpool, your updated answer is for an asynchronous send. Could you please add one for a synchronous send?

Answer (score 1):

You can try get() API of send , which will return the Future of RecordMetadata

```
ProducerRecord<String, String> record = 
new ProducerRecord<>("SampleTopic", "SampleKey", "SampleValue");

try {
    producer.send(record).get(); 
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Comment: @Chandra Mohan G, if the catch block is never executed, meaning that the .get() is "executed" successfully, can i say that the topic has received the message? Or do i need to check the RecordMetadata returned?

Answer (score 1):

Use exactly-once-delivery and you won't need to worry about whether your message reached or not: https://www.baeldung.com/kafka-exactly-once, https://www.confluent.io/blog/exactly-once-semantics-are-possible-heres-how-apache-kafka-does-it/

Comment: the problem lays in placing brokers on remote AWS server. If I put 'em locally everything works fine.
How your proposal could help me ?